# Many to many SQL select query to get matched records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

Endoscopy is many to one with Patient which is one to many with Histology

The histology is usually one to one with endoscopy but that relationship doesnt exist in the database only in real life

I want to get the histology for each patient's endoscopy where the date of the histology is the same as the date of the endoscopy

so far I have

```
select Endoscopy.*,Histology.Diagnosis
from Endoscopy
INNER JOIN PatientData
ON Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id
INNER JOIN Histology
ON Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id
```

However this results in a dataset where one (the first) endoscopy for a patient is duplicated for each histology records. How can I get the endoscopy related to the histology rather than this duplication?

Comment: Post your schema, representative sample data, and the desired result.

Comment: You're missing the where clause that matches up the date of the histology and the date of the endoscopy. Once you add that clause, I'd expect you'd get the results you're hoping for.

Comment: Where do you match your endoscopy and histology dates? `WHERE histology.date = endoscopy.date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For avoiding duplicate use distinct and add the condition on the date_of_test

```
    Select distinct 
        Endoscopy.*
        ,Histology.Diagnosis 
    from Endoscopy 
    INNER JOIN PatientData ON Endoscopy.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id 
    INNER JOIN Histology ON Histology.HospNum_Id=PatientData.HospNum_Id
    WHERE Histology.date_of_test = Endoscopy.date_of_test
```

Comment: OK. Yes. me being dumb. Thank you